# mlp classifier of scikit-neuralnetwork not working for xor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to create a neural network which can learn xor problem using scikit-neuralnetwork. I'm getting output of 1 for everything

```
import sknn.mlp as mlp;
import numpy as np; 
""" input layer """
ip_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=2);
hidden_layer = mlp.Layer('Tanh', units=3);
op_layer = mlp.Layer('Softmax', units=1);
nn = mlp.Classifier([ip_layer, hidden_layer, op_layer], n_iter=10000);
nn.fit(np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [0,1], [1,1]]), np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]]));
print nn.predict(np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]))
```

it predicts [[1], [1], [1], [1]].
There is another question on stack overflow itself which tried similar code but I was unable to understand the solution and it did not allow me to post comment
[scikit-neuralnetwork mismatch error in dataset size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017880/scikit-neuralnetwork-mismatch-error-in-dataset-size)

It gives me following warning. I'm not sure if it is relevant.

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/signal/downsample.py:6:
>   UserWarning: downsample module has been moved to the
>   theano.tensor.signal.pool module.   "downsample module has been moved
>   to the theano.tensor.signal.pool module.") [(4, 1)]

Answer (score 2):

With your original code I get `AssertionError: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer.`

I've modified your code to have `units=2` for the output layer (this seems to be key), and got the correct prediction output of `[[0], [1], [1], [0]]`

```
import sknn.mlp as mlp;                                            
import numpy as np;

ip_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=2)
hidden_layer = mlp.Layer('Tanh', units=3)
op_layer = mlp.Layer('Softmax', units=2) # <-- units=2, not 1

nn = mlp.Classifier(
    [ip_layer, hidden_layer, op_layer],
    n_iter=10000
)

x_train = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
y_train = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

nn.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_predict = nn.predict(x_train)

print 'y_predict is', y_predict
```

**The output trace with correct prediction**

```
x_train is [[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 1]]
y_predict is [[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]]
```

**My environment versions**

```
Python 2.7.9

>>> np.__version__
'1.11.0'
>>> sknn.__version__
u'0.7'
>>> lasagne.__version__
'0.1'
>>> theano.__version__
'0.8.2'
```

**Theano warning**

As for the warning `UserWarning: downsample module has been moved to the theano.tensor.signal.pool module.`, this seems to be benign and simply an interface change in the library, updating the `theano` version to `0.8.0` should fix it (`sknn` uses `lasagne` and `theano` underneath)

ref https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/605

ref https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/pull/644

Comment: Thanks a lot. Mine doesn't work if I make it into two units. Could that be because I'm using a different version or something? I get the same error AssertionError: Mismatch between dataset size and units in output layer.

Comment: Added my versions to the answer, hope that helps!

Comment: I am using numpy version of 1.8.2. Rest everything is similar to yours. Python version is 2.7.6.

Comment: It might also be a bug, https://github.com/aigamedev/scikit-neuralnetwork/issues/140

Comment: Thanks! The bug has not been assigned to anyone. Should I follow it up there?

Comment: I used get_parameters call to find the parameters. Following results I got
[Parameters(weights=array([[ 0.89525994,  0.2651286 ],
       [ 0.94294777, -0.70232577]]), biases=array([ 0.24056143, -0.01097659]), layer=u'hidden0'), Parameters(weights=array([[-1.32513065, -0.88440514,  1.19780965],
       [-0.39852208,  0.37491247,  0.03918179]]), biases=array([-0.40321062,  0.12814087,  1.07872618]), layer=u'hidden1'), Parameters(weights=array([[-0.46229523],
       [ 0.73323931],
       [ 3.21744843]]), biases=array([ 3.00507573]), layer=u'output')]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are working on a binary classification problem, the output layer should use the Sigmoid activation function.

`op_layer = mlp.Layer('Sigmoid', units=1);`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this change. This doesn't seem to work. I am getting same output. I will go through the code again and get back to you :)